# 2018 Ford focus. First oil change

Tags: ford, oil-change, focus

I purchased a 2018 Ford Focus and have drove nearly 8,000. It's over 7,500 for sure. The oil light hasn't turned on even once. I know these newer cars can go a lot longer between oil changes but I'm worried about going to long.
Could the oil light be defected or is the oil still good?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I would change it regardless of the light, its the original oil and should be changed at this point.

Comment: What is the service / oil change interval as stated in the handbook / manual?

Comment: Typically, when you see the oil light, engine damage has already occurred.  You never want to see the oil light on your dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

Oil change intervals are much longer now than they used to be, 8000 miles doesn't sound too long. The [Ford owners portal](https://owner.ford.com/tools/account/maintenance/maintenance-schedule.html#/ymm/2018/Ford/Focus/46) says the oil should be changed every 10,000 miles in your case, but put your details in to be sure.

The oil light only goes on if the oil gets very low, or has low pressure, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't check it. When you get home stop the car, then check the oil using the dipstick, the procedure should be pull it, wipe it, put it all the back in, then pull it out and check the level. If it's low top it up with the right kind of oil, don't just use anything. If the level is very low and the sensor hasn't come on then it should be checked.

Comment: Does the oil light come on for low level or low pressure or both?

Comment: It's a pressure sensor @SolarMike

Answer (score 1):

You folks are confused
The oil light on the dashboard is not the same thing as the oil change indicator from the computer
The engine has a sensor that evaluates oil condition independent from the mileage and signals when oil is approaching end of useful life maybe 8000 or more miles depending on vehicle use and driving habits
The oil light only monitors level and pressure of the oil system it has nothing to do with oil life or change intervals

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, the oil light *could* be defective, but either way I would have changed the oil by now. It's possible it'll go on around 10,000 but I'd go ahead and change it now anyway.